# Is Pentaho able to display crosstab like in Excel?

Tags: pentaho

I want to get tabular view like an Excel crosstab : there are column values on a horizontal line and other values on a vertical line , and fact data are in the middle. Is that possible with Pentaho ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Pentaho report designer support crosstabs.